# How to get images intensity matrix from Nifti images with Nibabel?

Tags: python, nifti, nibabel

I'm new with NiBabel. I want to know how to get intensity matrix from a Nifti images with this library. I use the following script to get voxels:

```
import nibabel as ni
example_img = ni.load('myImage.nii')

data = example_img.get_data()
```

I thought at beginning that data contains the voxels' intensity, but when I've printed it, I've seen negative values, it seems strange to have a negative intensity within an image, don't you think?

I need to get the voxels' intensity within a nifti image, is it possible with nibabel? If not, can you propose me an other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you're getting negative voxel values, but here's a way to display a NifTi image as a matrix:

```
import nibabel as ni
img = ni.load('myImage.nii')

data = example_img.get_data()

mat = []

for i in range(img.shape[0]):
  plane = []
  for j in range(img.shape[1]):
    row = []
    for k in range(img.shape[2]):
        row.append(data[i][j][k])
    plane.append(row)
  mat.append(plane)
```

Now you can print out/store in a text file the variable "mat".

Answer (score 2):

No. You can have negatives and nan.

These represent voxels outside the brain.
The intensity is just the output of

```
data = example_img.get_fdata()
```

Note: use `get_fdata` and not `get_data`, to always get floating point numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Another direct method to use is [`nltools`](https://neurolearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) :: `Brain_Data` function to extract the data directly into an 1d array. Although not `Nibabel` but is similar to your logic.

```
from nltools.data import Brain_Data
img = Brain_Data('myImage.nii')
data = img.data
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what seralouk has said in the [earlier answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56648011/2893606), Since we are dealing with 'nii' nifti images, it is possible for voxel value to be negative. For example, if it were a CT scan, then each voxel stores values in [Hounsfield unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale), in which case 0 represents attenuation through water, whereas attenuation through air is -1000.